# Where can I get health insurance for an Indian traveler in Japan with type 1 diabetes?

Tags: indian-citizens, japan, health, insurance

I am from India and I have type 1 diabetes with no complications. I am looking for health insurance for my stay in Japan, which will be for a maximum of 90 days, but I have found it difficult to find any.

Can someone suggest companies that can help me with that? I will bring all my required medicine with me and will not need to buy any from Japan; I just need insurance for safety and emergency purposes.

Answer (score 1):

This is specifically for travel insurance from India.

You can compare policies using policy bazaar with your preexisting conditions. It will list the providers that supports it and you can compare.

https://travel.policybazaar.com/